# How to provide additional custom implementation of accessor methods when using @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, accessor

I want to fire some code when a property is accessed and changed. I use `@property` and `@synthesize` in my code for my ivars. The properties are retained, so I'd like to keep that memory management stuff automatically generated by `@synthesize`.

However, I assume that `@synthesize` tells the compiler to generate the accessor methods code right where `@synthesize is`, so most of the cases at the top of the code, right?

And when I have a property `foo`, I get `-setFoo` and `-foo` methods. Could I then just make a method like this, to execute some more custom code when a property is changed?

```
-(void)setFoo {
    // custom stuff
}
```

Now that's a problem. How to execute the first one? I wouldn't love to have a different name here. Is there maybe a way to let the `@synthesize` directive create other names for getter and setter methods, which I then call easily? And I would still be able to use the dot syntax then to access them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@property` and `@synthesize` just like you normally would, but provide a custom setter or getter (or both) and those will be used instead. Typically I will do something like this:

```
// Override the setter
- (void)setName:(NSString *)aName
{
    if (name == aName)
        return;

    [name release];
    name = [aName retain];

    //custom code here
}
```

When I use the set property, it will invoke my custom method. However, the get will still be synthesized.

Comment: FYI, your example setter has a bug, in that calling it twice with the same object can cause that object to be dealloced before it's retained. Not a really big deal, but it illustrates how difficult it can be to get these things exactly right.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you explain how it should be written instead (it's not that I don't believe you, I'd like to know how to do it properly). Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, nvm I see the problem, I'll update it to reflect the changes.

Comment: another way that avoids the if statement is: [aName retain]; [name release]; name = aName;

Comment: Would the if statement be faster though? It's just comparing two pointers and possibly returning early. Where the alternative calls the two methods and then assigns regardless? (I know it's not really a big deal in the long run)

Comment: Usually, when we're calling setSomething:object, object should have a retain count of >1 right? I mean from the caller POV, they shouldn't give another object something with a retain count of zero, right? (release should be called *after* sets anyway) So I think [name release]; name = [aName retain]; should be just fine in most cases.

Comment: Is this retain/release shuffle still needed under ARC? And is there any other magic that the synthesized setter might be doing (like with all the various modifiers like `strong` and `nonatomic` and whatnot) that we would have to mimic?

Answer (score 1):

If you provide an implemnetation for the setters or getters  it will use that instead of the generated implementation. Its not hard to implement the "retaining" aspect of the getters and setters that are generated for you by the compiler when u synthesize, so you can just write your own getters and setters i would say and go with that.

Answer (score 0):

One wacky solution is to create an abstract super class that does gives you the normal property synthesis.
Then create a concrete subclass that you will actually use, and that simply implements and override method (same signature) and calls super to do the actual setting.
This allows you to do whatever you want to do before or after the call to super's implementation.

Example:

```
@interface ALTOClassA : NSObject


@property NSString *catName;

@end
```

Nothing else needed in the .m beyond the stubbed file for this test.

Create the subclass, nothing needed specially in the @interface

```
#import "ALTOClassA.h"

@interface ALTOClassAJunior : ALTOClassA

@end
```

In the @implementation we do our override.

```
#import "ALTOClassAJunior.h"

@implementation ALTOClassAJunior


- (void)setCatName:(NSString*)aCatName {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [super setCatName:aCatName];
    NSLog(@"after super: self.catName %@", self.catName);
}
@end
```

In use:

```
    ALTOClassAJunior *aCAJ = [ALTOClassAJunior new];
NSLog(@"aCAS.catName %@", aCAJ.catName);

NSLog(@"set it to George.");

[aCAJ setCatName:@"George"];

NSLog(@"aCAS.catName %@", aCAJ.catName);
```

This allows you to leverage the autogenerated code, and still do stuff you want to do with your class. Abstract Super Class is often a useful solution for many things.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in your @property declaration, you can specify the getter and setter methods.

```
@property (readwrite,getter=privateGetFoo,setter=privateSetFoo:) NSObject * foo;
```

In your `foo` and `setFoo:` methods, call `[self privateGetFoo]` or `[self privateSetFoo:f]` then your custom code.

The object can also set an observer on itself with `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`.

That said, I don't think either of these are very clean ways to do things.  Better to write your own getter/setter as others have suggested.

Comment: You said: "In your foo and setFoo: methods..." While [obj setFoo: x] and [obj foo] are available, it is important to note that due to the modified property, obj.foo will not be available for writing, and you'll have to use obj.setFoo = x.  This is not the way @property normally does it, where obj.foo is used for both reading and writing.

Comment: Then object.foo is equivalent to [object privateFoo], which defeats the entire purpose of using properties.